# Why apple don't recommend JPG files?

Tags: ios, iphone, design-guidelines

According to Apple guidelines, they recommend all images to be png.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

I have a big background, which is almost 1.5 mb in PNG and 150 Kb in JPG.
Having smaller image size will help me in smaller app size.

Can I use JPG file, or it will be against Apple guidelines.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JPEGs will not be against Apple guidelines. However you will not be able to use transparent images with JPEGs as they don't have an alpha channel.

Comment: Thanks! My developer was asking me to strictly provide PNG, no matter what, and that was illogical. Thanks for answering :)